# Do the Jedi deal with non-Force users?

Tags: star-wars, jedi

In most of the Star Wars media I've seen, it always seems like the Jedi only concern themselves with other Force users. It seems like they only got involved in the Clone Wars because of the Sith influence.

Do they ever deal with non-Force users/non-Force based threats?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Of course. To name just a couple from an emormous amount of examples:

- [Mandalorian Wars](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Mandalorian_Wars) (though Sith were somewhat involved in that, the main drive was Madalore the Ultimate)
- Obi-Wan and Qui-Gon tussled with Trade Federation way before any Sith connection was known.
- Post-Empire New Jedi Order pretty much exclusively dealt with non-Force-related threats (up to and including cut-off-from-the Force Yuuzhan Vong

Comment: Do they ever get involved in say, tracking down individual law breakers? Everything you mention is on the larger scale.

Comment: @Pureferret - at the very least, there are Service Corps for people who didn't complete Jedi Training. As far as individual criminals, that'd be kind of a stupid waste of resources, no?

Comment: That's what I thought...

Answer (score 2):

> For over a thousand generations, the Jedi Knights were the guardians of peace and justice in the Old Republic.

That was Obi-wan explaining who the Jedi were in A New Hope.

It stands to reason that there are threats to peace and justice other than Sith. Before Episode II, the Jedi hadn't encountered the Sith in a thousand years, and yet still stood as "the guardians of peace and justice".

Furthermore, the prequels are instructive, because we get to see how the Jedi operate and are viewed before their downfall. I don't have quotes at the moment but you are given the impression that the Jedi are 1) frequently deployed as uncommonly effective emissaries and negotiators by the Republic to deal with situations like illegal embargoes, 2) serve as protectors of threatened senators, and will chase down and investigate assassins, across the galaxy if need be, and 3) serve as generals during wars, though it's impossible to say how common this was, if at all, before the Clone Wars.

Answer (score 0):

The Jedi did get involved with non force users and lesser crimes at times, but only when those crimes might be part of something larger. Just as the FBI or Homeland security would only get invovled with the local police if a crime might have a connection to something larger. The Jedi would also work with local police in the course of their investigations if it was warranted.

If they happen to be on a mission and they saw a lesser crime, they would intervene and chase down a minor criminal to assist the local authorities.

Comment: Example: Obi-One telling a drug pusher not to do that anymore in Episode 2

Comment: Correct. When Obi-Wan used the force to tell the death stick dealer "You don't want to sell me death sticks... you want to go home and rethink your life". Also as Asoka and other Jedi would at times chase down regular local criminals as shown in the Clone Wars cartoon series and other examples from the books exist as well.